# Is Dev Mode still broken in Hyperledger Fabric 2.X?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, dev-mode

Is Dev Mode still broken in Hyperledger Fabric 2.X? I looked at the jira (https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-17584) and it has been resolved. I looked at the jira in the comments too and they have also been resolved. Based on this, I think the Dev Mode is working already.

However, when I tried running my chaincode in Dev Mode, I ran into a problem. It got stuck in building the chaincode and would not instantiate it. (It works on net mode though.)

I just want to clarify if Dev Mode is still in fact broken. If it works, please provide a link as to how to use it properly.